# Need new eyes on this script getting a 417 error cod

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I get this error in the Google Sheets application trying to text reminders every day I used this format 4175555555, (417) 5555555, and (417) 5555555 you are not sure what the problems are.

The error is:

> Request failed for api.fluentcloud.com/v1/sms/send/GeneralRentalCenter returned code 417. Truncated server response: {"error":{"code":417,"message":"Expectation Failed: To number: is not formatted properly"}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 25, file "REMINDER")

```
//This sends out sms to phone number in row
function sendSms(to, name, time) {
    var messages_url = 'https://api.fluentcloud.com/v1/sms/send/GeneralRentalCenter';

    var body = {
        'direction': '',
        'to': to,
        'from': '(417) 886-7368',
        'timestamp': '',
        'message': 'Hello' + ' ' + name + ', This is a reminder of your reservation at General Rental at ' + time + ' tomorrow. If you have any questions call 417-886-7368 ',
        'messageId': '',
        'particContactName': ''
    };

    var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "payload": body
    };

    options.headers = {
        "Authorization": "4LsEvTFn-jD4i-XOmg-iGEXji7x2ZTb"
    };

    //sends out SMS to number for the row
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
};

function sendAll() {
    var date = new Date();
    var today = ((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear());
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    var activeSheet;
    for (i in sheets) {
        if ((((new Date(today)) - (new Date(sheets[i].getName()))) / 86400000) === -1) {
            activeSheet = sheets[i].getName();
            SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheets[i]);
        }
    }

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    var startRow = 2;
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 8, numRows, 4);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        if (!row[1]) {
            continue;
        };

        var num = row[1].toString().split(".")[0];
        if (row[3] === 'y') {
            `enter code here`
            try {
                response_data = sendSms(num, row[0], row[2]);
            } catch (err) {
                Logger.log(err);
            }
        }
    }
};

function myFunction() {
    sendAll();
}
```

When script works it should pull there name,number and items and send out a reminder to them

Comment: First, can you take a moment and indent your code?  Second, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: I see the text `\`enter code here\`` in the middle of your code. Is this really present in your code, or did you misclick while composing your question?

Comment: Pretty clear that the problem is the formatting of `to`. FWIW, this is the FluentCloud Developer API reference for sending sms (https://jsapi.apiary.io/apis/fluentstream/reference/sms/create-and-recieve/post-send-sms.html), and their example format for `to` is `"to": "(720) 204-4986",`. This doesn't look like one of the formats that you have tried.